# Are quantum locked things slowed down by air resistance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, superconductivity, drag, levitation

Me and my friend had an argument today whether [**Quantum Locked**](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5850729/quantum-locking-will-blow-your-mind--but-how-does-it-work) objects are slowed down by air resistance? He says that it isn't, that the magnetic field or something removes the air resistance. Could anybody just say that it isn't, just so I can prove it, and maybe even give a scientific explanation to it (not that it is anything advanced...)

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) It might help if you defined the words you are using (e.g., quantum locked) and sketch the experimental setup in which you would or would not expect air resistance.

Comment: The magnetic rail is a circle that is on flat ground. Also, assume that the object levitating is permanently cooled, and has completely no electric resistance. I know this question might be stupid, I just want to prove that it's slowed down by air resistance. Basically my question is if a quantum.

Comment: Basically my question is if quantum locked objects are slowed down by air resistance. (I accidentally submitted the previous comment before I were done)

Comment: I edited in a link to a description of quantum locking, you might find it useful, or change it to a site you prefer.

Comment: The link is broken for me, takes me to `http/http://io9.giz...` instead of `http://io9.giz...`

Comment: @jmona789   works ok for me, but  just case anybody else has the same problem:  http://io9.gizmodo.com/5850729/quantum-locking-will-blow-your-mind--but-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. (Source: I perform similar demonstrations at public outreach events pretty regularly.) The disk is (necessarily) pretty thin and not traveling very fast, so it doesn't have a lot of air resistance, but it does have some and will slow if you watch long enough.

You did ask for a scientific explanation, so let me add some more explanation: the function of the magnetic field in this demonstration is only to control the YBaCo disk. It doesn't affect the air, as air is not magnetic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We had a long argument about it, I will show my friend this! Thanks again! Now I can prove I'm right! Hehe... 